# Update Supplier Invoices as Paid by an Account via API on SAP Business ByDesign

Tags: rest, soap, erp, sap-business-bydesign

Currently, I'm integrating with **SAP Business ByDesign**. I already using the **OData** API's that I customized and some of the **SOAP web services**. Anyway, the last thing I have to do is to pay the supplier invoices through our *3rd party* system via ACH and we already have all the data we need to make the payment.

It happens that after make the payments at the bank, we need to update the SAP and tell it that we paid the given invoices with a given house bank account to reflect the changes in our registries.

Anyway, I've already tried to customize a bunch of SAP objects inside the OData Modeler, but I was never able to find an action attached to any of these objects. I've looked for a SOAP API and even made some changes in the configurations of our SAP. Yet, no success.

Apparently, what I'm looking for is an `Outgoing Bank Transfer` that I was able to create via web interface. I found this object on the OData Modeler, but no action attached to it.

Right now, I have no leads on how to solve this. Is there anyone there that could help me? Even with some leads.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I could not get a definitive and straight answer, even among the SAP Community and the official support. Apparently, SAP has a policy of automating the payment routines inside the ERP, abstracting this part. So, it appears they don't provide an official way of doing that.

So, you would need to implement your service or adapt to an existing one. For now, I'm using the service `ManageCashPaymentOrderIn` (Maintain cash payments with reference to items), docs here:

https://help.sap.com/doc/a2b4c7ef61d64397b2b1d052082a8a08/1911/en-US/PSM_ISI_R_II_FOP_MANAGE_PAYORD_CASH_IN.html